# FUSE mapping to Google Persistent Disks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to mount the [FUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io/) storage to a Google Persistent Disk(Standard persistent disk)?

Comment: You mean to mount a GCS bucket on a Persistent disk on a Compute through FUSE?

Comment: Yes, maybe - as long I can access the data

Comment: But a Cloud Storage bucket  is not a Cloud Disk?

Comment: No, you cannot FUSE mount Cloud Storage as a Persistent Disk. You can FUSE mount Cloud Storage as a folder that exists on a Persistent Disk as a normal Linux mount point which means the Persistent Disk must also be mounted with a supported file system.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cloud Storage FUSE, which is a FUSE adapter that allows you to mount buckets as file systems on Linux or macOS systems.

Cloud Storage FUSE can be run anywhere with connectivity to Cloud Storage, including Google Compute Engine VMs or on-premises systems. So it probably will suit whichever needs your system have.

If this is the way you choose to go, you can find more information on how it works and how to set it up in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse).

Comment: Do you know how to connect a Cloud Disk to a bucket - it that is the way it is done?

Comment: I dont think you can use a "bucket" with (Standard persistent disk)?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, as you can see here in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#gcsbuckets), persistent disks and buckets are different and unrelated storage products offered by GCP. Related to you first question, you can find information on how to connect to a bucket on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets). Hope this helps.